# Restrict access to an SVN repo to members of one group

Tags: svn, apache2

I have a few dozen SVN repos that must be accessible to all users, and a single repo that needs to be restricted to just one group. I've tried setting up my .svnaccess file like so:

```
[groups]
special = alice,bob

[/]
* = rw

[RestrictedRepo:/]
* = 
@special = rw
```

However, this results in even alice and bob being unable to access RestrictedRepo. If I use `~@special =` instead of `* =`, then I end up with all users having access. Moving the `* =` to the last line does not change anything.

Is there any way I can do this without setting root permissions to nothing  and giving explicit access to all non-group members on each of my many other repos?

I'm running this on an older server with svn 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the apache config contained these lines:

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

This allows unauthenticated access to the server for all read operations. It appears I will need to either require login for all reads (by removing the LimitExcept specifier around the Require) or implement something like what's described at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir to get mixed authenticated and anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the same configuration on my server and it works. Did you restart the svnserve service (assuming you're on a linux system) after editing your configuration ?

From this [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.groups) about subversion, it says :

> Another important fact is that group permissions are not overridden by individual user permissions. Rather, the combination of all matching permissions is granted. [...] Permissions for group members can only be extended beyond the permissions the group already has. Restricting users who are part of a group to less than their group's permissions is impossible.

For me your configuration is correct, alice and bob should have access to the RestrictedRepo.

Comment: I'm serving it through apache2, and I did restart apache after each change to the file.

Perhaps it makes a difference that this is a fairly old server running svn 1.5.1?

Comment: On version 1.5.*, the first matching rule is the one which gets applied to a user. Try put * = after @special = rw

Comment: I've just tried it with the `* = ` last, and it still won't give group members read access